# Lookup from a pandas dataframe given a multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, kaggle

While playing with the kaggle titanic dataset with pandas I found one place where I wrote an explicit loop in python, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way? Consider the following program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pandas as pd

# Assume that we have a dataframe with three fields
f = pd.DataFrame([ (0,1,1),
                   (1,0,0),
                   (1,1,1),
                   (1,1,0),
                   ],
                 columns=list('ABY'))

# and a multi index of A,B
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([(0,1),(0,1)],
                                 names=list('AB'))

# For each idx I want a list of the values of F.Y for which A and B match. This
# can be done through the following loop:
e = []
for a,b in idx:
  e += [list(f.Y[(f.A==a) & (f.B==b)])]

s = pd.Series(e, index=idx, name='Y')
print s

# Yields:
# A  B
# 0  0        []
#    1       [1]
# 1  0       [0]
#    1    [1, 0]
# Name: Y, dtype: object
```

My question is whether it is possible to generate `s` without the loop?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way that is almost the same:

```
>>> f.groupby(["A", "B"])["Y"].apply(list).ix[idx]
A  B
0  0       NaN
   1       [1]
1  0       [0]
   1    [1, 0]
dtype: object
```

The only difference is that this gives NaN instead of an empty list in the case where there is no match.  Unfortunately you cannot use `fillna` to replace the NaN with an empty list due to [this issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3435).  However, you can drop it with `dropna`, and in many cases you won't really need the empty item for the cases with no match anyway.